# Convert string representation of list of objects back to list in python

Tags: python, string, list, object

I have a list of objects, that has been stringified:

```
u'[<object: objstuff1, objstuff2>, <object: objstuff1, objstuff2>]'
```

I want to convert this back into a list:

```
[<object: objstuff1, objstuff2>, <object: objstuff1, objstuff2>]
```

I've tried using `ast.literal_eval()`, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work if the elements are objects, and I get a `SyntaxError`.

Is there any way I can reconvert my string representation of the list of objects back into a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a look at the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html) module to do this.

Basically, dump your objects using [`pickle.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps), and load them back using [`pickle.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads).

`ast.literal_eval` doesn't work obviously, because there is a lot of information related to the objects (like attributes, and values) which is simply not captured in that string. Also note that you will be able to *resurrect only* the pickled data, if all you have are those string representations right now, you won't be able to create the objects back from them because of the information loss.